# How do I pass Haskell data through a C FFI as an opaque data type?

Tags: haskell, ffi

I'm trying to pass some data through a C library that doesn't read or modify that data.

```
foreign import ccall "lua.h lua_pushlightuserdata"
  c_lua_pushlightuserdata :: LuaState -> Ptr a -> IO ()

foreign import ccall "lua.h lua_touserdata"
  c_lua_touserdata :: LuaState -> CInt -> IO (Ptr a)

data MyData =
  MyData
  { dataIds = TVar [Int]
  , dataSomethingElse = [String]
  }

calledFromRunLuaState :: LuaState -> IO ()
calledFromRunLuaState luaState = do
  dataPtr <- c_lua_touserdata luaState (-1)
  myData <- dataFromPtr dataPtr
  doSomethingWith myData

main = do
  luaState <- Lua.newstate
  ids <- atomically $ newTVar []
  c_lua_pushlightuserdata luaState (dataToPtr (MyData ids []))
  runLuaState luaState
```

I'm trying to figure out how to define `dataFromPtr` and `dataToPtr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [StablePtr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Foreign-StablePtr.html#t:StablePtr) is for. So you have to use [newStablePtr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Foreign-StablePtr.html#v:newStablePtr) in place of your `dataFromPtr` and [deRefStablePtr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Foreign-StablePtr.html#v:deRefStablePtr) in place of your `dataToPtr`. Note that `deRefStablePtr` operates in the `IO` monad, so you would have to ajust your code accordingly. Also, you would have to adjust the foreign imports to use stable pointers, e.g.:

```
foreign import ccall "lua.h lua_pushlightuserdata"
  c_lua_pushlightuserdata :: LuaState -> StablePtr MyData -> IO ()
```

and similarly for `lua_touserdata`.

Finally, when you create a stable pointer with `newStablePtr`, the garbage collector will not deallocate that value automatically. So it is your responsibility to deallocate it by calling [freeStablePtr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Foreign-StablePtr.html#v:freeStablePtr).

Comment: Thanks! I saw StablePtr, but I didn't quite get it. Maybe I need a third cup of coffee.